# read -e removes the whole line

Tags: bash, shell, readline

I'm using Bash for my script with `read` command to input last name and first name. Last name and first name descriptions are on the same line in the output. Now having a `-e` parameter in `read` can perform delete with `backspace` key, however, all characters along this line will be removed when performing the delete. Is there any way to prevent this?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
tput cup 0 25
echo -n "First Name: JOHN"
tput cup 0 0
echo -n "Last Name: " $lastname
read -e -n10 lastname
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If you want to read two values from a single line, use two variables: `read -r firstname lastname` (where `-r` is basically always a good idea unless you specifically require the odd logacy behavior around backslashes).

Comment: I avoid using -r parameter because it cannot limit the characters you input. In my case I use -n10 to do that to limit to 10 characters only. Now, given the First Name: JOHN as displayed in the console as output along with Last Name: $lastname on the same line, the First Name: JOHN will be removed when performing $lastname backspace delete.

Comment: Which features of [Readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Editing.html) do you utilize here?

Comment: @Armali I did not set anything with Readline command-line editing which I believe it is using the default, Emacs like editor but after reading I've tried adding set -o vi in the script but still the same outcome.

Comment: Is it possible to start editing the line within the declared number of characters? Let say -n10 and backspace will start at 10nth character moving to left until 1st and not the whole single-line?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to start editing the line within the declared number of characters?

`read -e` does this if you add the option `-i`, provided that the current variable value's length is *within the declared number of characters*; e. g.:

```
read -ei"$lastname" -n10 lastname
```

> Let say -n10 and backspace will start at 10nth character moving to left until 1st and not the whole single-line?

The cursor already does not move back beyond its position at the beginning of input in all cases I see presently.
But as the behavior can depend on e. g. shell version and terminal capabilities, you might prefer something like

```
newname=`dialog --max-input 10 \
                --inputbox "First Name: JOHN\nLast Name: " 0 0 "$lastname" \
         2>&1 >/dev/tty` && lastname="$newname"; clear
```

Comment: Thank you @Armali for your response however as tried, the outcome is just the same as ``read -n10 lastname``.

Comment: As additional info, I'm using bash-4.4.19-12.el8.aarch64 in CentOS 8.

Comment: Does _the outcome is just the same_ mean that even with `-ei"$lastname"` the cursor is not positioned after the current `$lastname`'s last character?